# Visual Studio project template error

Tags: visual-studio, project-template

I created a Visual Studio template by using the export template wizard. But when I create a new project from that template system namespaces red underlined. It says "Namespace not defined". Can someone help me?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally msdn answered to this. This is a bug of the Visual Studio update1. We posted a bug in the vs thread. reffer the below link 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2417426

If someone face this issue go to this link and vote,comment it.